# Error handling while searching Python lists

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to calculate a few metrics around an orderbook, and looking for how deep I need to go in to fill an order of $x. I have created a list of lists that shows the price and cumulative asks, and then am finding how deep I need to go under cumulative asks >= x. However, depending on the orderbook and x, sometimes I don't have enough data and end up with a list index out of range error. How can I set some sort of default, None, N/A, whatever, when this is the case.

Note: I feel like there may be a better way than creating a list with the >= and then filtering for first elements of that list, so if that makes solving the index out of range error easier, that'd be great, too.

```
cum_ob = [[1.54325, 4296.408], [1.5449, 5862.9366], [1.54495, 7679.7978], [1.545, 7695.2478], [1.5467, 7696.7945]]

usd_5k = ([sublist for sublist in cum_ob if sublist[-1] >= 5000][0][0])
usd_10k = ([sublist for sublist in cum_ob if sublist[-1] >= 10000][0][0])
```

So usd_5k would return 1.5449, while usd_10k throws the error since I've exhausted these levels without reaching 10000.

Comment: You can store the result of the list comprehension and use a condition to check if it has elements before indexing into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should write a function to do it rather than using list comprehension that it not so flexible for your case :

```py
def search_for_amount(cumulative_list, threshold):

    for order in cumulative_list:
        
        if order[1] >= threshold:
            return order   # You return a tuple with (element, cumulative sum)

    # If nothing was found, return None
    return None
```

Then you would be able to get your previous values as follow :

```py
usd_5k = search_for_amount(cum_ob, 5000)   # Returns (1.5449, 5862)
usd_10k = search_for_amount(cum_ob, 10000) # Returns None
```

One advantage of this technique compared to yours is that you do not need to go through the whole list each time. You just iterate until you find a value that matches the threshold condition. With your technique, you have to iterate over every elements of the list, every time, even though the first element matches the condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`more_itertools` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) `first_true`, pasted below. It takes 3 arguments: the iterable (your list), a `default` for what should be returned if the condition is not met and your list is exhausted; and a `predicate` (condition) which will be the >=5/10k check.

Since your list has pairs of values, I've set the default to `[None, None]` so when you index `[0]` of the returned value, you'll get `None`, or the price.

```py
usd_5k = first_true(cum_ob, default=[None, None], pred=lambda sub: sub[1] >= 5_000)[0]
print(usd_5k)
# 1.5449

usd_10k = first_true(cum_ob, default=[None, None], pred=lambda sub: sub[1] >= 10_000)[0]
print(usd_10k)
# None
```

For the `first_true` code, you can either copy-paste the code or install `more_itertools` - the body is just one line.

```py
# from https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes
def first_true(iterable, default=False, pred=None):
    """Returns the first true value in the iterable.

    If no true value is found, returns *default*

    If *pred* is not None, returns the first item
    for which pred(item) is true.

    """
    # first_true([a,b,c], x) --> a or b or c or x
    # first_true([a,b], x, f) --> a if f(a) else b if f(b) else x
    return next(filter(pred, iterable), default)
```